django cannot show user count when i called it
i'm new to django and i'm stuck here, when i want to show my total user excluding is_staff and is_superuser it cannot show what i wanted. Here's the code :
Views.py
def dashboard_view(request):
    # Menghitung jumlah user yang bukan staff dan bukan superuser
    user_count = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).count()
    return render(request, 'dashboardowner/index.html', {'user_count': user_count})

Urls.py :
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',include(router.urls)),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^booking$', booking, name='booking'),
    re_path(r'^layanan$', layanan, name='layanan'),
    re_path(r'^about$', about, name='about'),
    path('bookingadmin/',bookingadmin),
    path('layananadmin/',layananadmin),
    path('layanan/',layanan),
    path('index_book',index_book),
    path('tambahbooking/',tambahbooking),
    path('tambahlayanan/',tambahlayanan),
    path('book/ubah/<str:kode_id>',ubahbooking, name = "ubahbooking"),
    path('layanan/ubah/<str:namalayanan_id>',ubahlayanan, name = "ubahlayanan"),
    path('book/hapus/<str:kode_id>',hapusbooking, name = "hapusbooking"),
    path('layanan/hapus/<str:namalayanan_id>',hapuslayanan, name = "hapuslayanan"),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',LogoutView.as_view(next_page='home'), name='logout'),
    path('register/',register, name='register'),
    path('registeradmin/',registeradmin, name='registeradmin'),
    path('registerowner/',registerowner, name='registerowner'),
    path('export/xls/', export_xls, name='export_xls'),
    path('send_otp/', send_otp, name='send_otp'),
    re_path(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^home$', index, name='home'),
    re_path(r'^bookingadmin$', bookingadmin, name='bookingadmin'),
    re_path(r'^layananadmin$', layananadmin, name='layananadmin'),
    re_path(r'^index_book$', index_book, name='index_book'),
    path('dashboarduser/', views.dashboard_user, name='dashboard_user'),
    path('dashboardstaff/', views.dashboard_staff, name='dashboard_staff'),
    path('dashboardowner/', views.dashboard_owner, name='dashboard_owner'),
    path('change_pass/', change_user_password, name='change_pass'),
    path('pass_change_success/', views.CustomPasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='pass_change_success'),
    path('dashboardowner/index/', views.dashboard_view, name='dashboard_view'),

index.html (this file is inside dashboardowner folder, so here is the structure (mysalon->templates->dashboardowner->index.html))
{% extends 'basedashboard.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/style.css' %}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DarkPan - Bootstrap 5 Admin Template</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta content="" name="description">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="{% static 'dashboard/img/favicon.ico' %}" rel="icon">

    <!-- Google Web Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&family=Roboto:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    
    <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Libraries Stylesheet -->
<link href="{% static 'dashboard/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'dashboard/lib/tempusdominus/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Customized Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
<link href="{% static 'dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template Stylesheet -->
<link href="{% static 'dashboard/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid position-relative d-flex p-0">
        <!-- Spinner Start -->
        <div id="spinner" class="show bg-dark position-fixed translate-middle w-100 vh-100 top-50 start-50 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Spinner End -->


        <!-- Sidebar Start -->
<div class="sidebar pe-4 pb-3">
    <nav class="navbar bg-secondary navbar-dark flex-column">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand mx-4 mb-3">
            <h4 class="mb-0 text-danger text-uppercase"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" height="50" width="50" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail img-responsive"> Glory Salon</h4>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
            <li><a href="{% url 'dashboard_user'%}" class="nav-item nav-link active"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'booking' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Bookingku</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'layanan' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Layanan</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'layanan' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Daftar ACC</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'layanan' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Daftar User</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'layanan' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Daftar Staff</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'change_pass' %}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Password</a></li>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- Sidebar End -->


        <!-- Content Start -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Navbar Start -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-secondary navbar-dark sticky-top px-4 py-0">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex d-lg-none me-4">
                    <h2 class="text-primary mb-0"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i></h2>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
                <form class="d-none d-md-flex ms-4">
                    <input class="form-control bg-dark border-0" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
                <div class="navbar-nav align-items-center ms-auto">
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell me-lg-2"></i>
                            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-flex">Pemberitahuan</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end bg-secondary border-0 rounded-0 rounded-bottom m-0">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                <h6 class="fw-normal mb-0">Profile updated</h6>
                                <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                            </a>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                <h6 class="fw-normal mb-0">New user added</h6>
                                <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                            </a>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                <h6 class="fw-normal mb-0">Password changed</h6>
                                <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                            </a>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item text-center">See all notifications</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-flex">Welcome Back, {{ user.username }}</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end bg-secondary border-0 rounded-0 rounded-bottom m-0">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">My Profile</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Settings</a>
                            <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- Navbar End -->


            <!-- Sale & Revenue Start -->
            <div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
                <div class="row g-4">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="bg-secondary rounded d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-4">
                            <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-3x text-primary"></i>
                            <div class="ms-3">
                                <p class="mb-2">Total Bookingan</p>
                                <h6 class="mb-0">$1234</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="bg-secondary rounded d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-4">
                            <i class="fa fa-chart-bar fa-3x text-primary"></i>
                            <div class="ms-3">
                                <p class="mb-2">Estimasi Pendapatan</p>
                                <h6 class="mb-0">$1234</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="bg-secondary rounded d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-4">
                            <i class="fa fa-chart-area fa-3x text-primary"></i>
                            <div class="ms-3">
                                <p class="mb-2">Jumlah Staff</p>
                                <h6 class="mb-0">$1234</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="bg-secondary rounded d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-4">
                            <i class="fa fa-chart-pie fa-3x text-primary"></i>
                            <div class="ms-3">
                                <p class="mb-2">Jumlah User</p>
                                <h6 class="mb-0">{{ user_count }}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Sale & Revenue End -->

            <!-- Recent Sales Start -->
            <div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
                <div class="bg-secondary text-center rounded p-4">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">Daftar Booking Anda</h6>
                        <a href="">Show All</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table text-start align-middle table-bordered table-hover mb-0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="text-white">
                                    <th scope="col"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></th>
                                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Invoice</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Customer</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td>01 Jan 2045</td>
                                    <td>INV-0123</td>
                                    <td>Jhon Doe</td>
                                    <td>$123</td>
                                    <td>Paid</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td>01 Jan 2045</td>
                                    <td>INV-0123</td>
                                    <td>Jhon Doe</td>
                                    <td>$123</td>
                                    <td>Paid</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td>01 Jan 2045</td>
                                    <td>INV-0123</td>
                                    <td>Jhon Doe</td>
                                    <td>$123</td>
                                    <td>Paid</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td>01 Jan 2045</td>
                                    <td>INV-0123</td>
                                    <td>Jhon Doe</td>
                                    <td>$123</td>
                                    <td>Paid</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    <td>01 Jan 2045</td>
                                    <td>INV-0123</td>
                                    <td>Jhon Doe</td>
                                    <td>$123</td>
                                    <td>Paid</td>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Recent Sales End -->


            <!-- Widgets Start -->
            <div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
                <div class="row g-4">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="h-100 bg-secondary rounded p-4">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-2">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">Messages</h6>
                                <a href="">Show All</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-bottom py-3">
                                <img class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" src="dashboard/img/user.jpg" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                                <div class="w-100 ms-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h6 class="mb-0">Jhon Doe</h6>
                                        <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Short message goes here...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-bottom py-3">
                                <img class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" src="dashboard/img/user.jpg" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                                <div class="w-100 ms-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h6 class="mb-0">Jhon Doe</h6>
                                        <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Short message goes here...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-bottom py-3">
                                <img class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" src="dashboard/img/user.jpg" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                                <div class="w-100 ms-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h6 class="mb-0">Jhon Doe</h6>
                                        <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Short message goes here...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-3">
                                <img class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" src="dashboard/img/user.jpg" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                                <div class="w-100 ms-3">
                                    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                                        <h6 class="mb-0">Jhon Doe</h6>
                                        <small>15 minutes ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Short message goes here...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="h-100 bg-secondary rounded p-4">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                                <h6 class="mb-0">Calender</h6>
                                <a href="">Show All</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="calender"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Widgets End -->


            <!-- Footer Start -->
            <div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
                <div class="bg-secondary rounded-top p-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 text-center text-sm-start">
                            &copy; <a href="#">Glory Salon</a>, All Right Reserved. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Footer End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Content End -->


        <!-- Back to Top -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-lg-square back-to-top"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/chart/chart.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/easing/easing.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/tempusdominus/js/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/tempusdominus/js/moment-timezone.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/lib/tempusdominus/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Template Javascript -->
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/js/main.js' %}"></script>

</body>

{% endblock %}

My CustomUser models :
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alamat = models.TextField()
    nohp = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name='custom_users')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nama','email','nohp','alamat']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

(edited) this is my basedashboard.html templates :
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GLORY SALON</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/animate/animate.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path/to/fontawesome.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'https://fonts.googleapis.com' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&family=Oswald:wght@600&display=swap' %}">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&family=Oswald:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/fontawesome.min.css">

<!-- Libraries Stylesheet -->
<link href="/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Customized Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Template Stylesheet -->
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body style="background-color:dark">

    
    
    {%block content%}
    
    
    {%endblock%}
    

    <script src="{% static 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' %}"></script> 
    <script src="{% static 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> 
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'lib/wow/wow.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script> 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

What i expected is the number of total user excluding staff and superuser is shown when i call (user_count)
Please help me

The code you shared should work though? What actually happens when you run this? Do you get an error? Or does it render a wrong value like 0 or some other number that doesn't match, or does it not render anything where the number should be?

Yes, it doesn't render any number, no number is shown in there when i run, so i am pretty confused

Please share a [mre] then, this code won't reproduce your problem.

Then maybe there's no normal users in db. Add some users using django admin and change is stuff and is superuser attributes.

Show us your CustomUser model code.

Hello, i already share the code example also i included the CustomUser models as you mention on the code, please take a look, sorry for burdening you

Your template looks quite weird to me. You're extending some basedashboard.html template but your content block basically seems to be the entire HTML document? Can you show that base template?

Thank you sir, i already edited and then provided the basedashboard.html code, also i'm sorry for the templates confusion because i took the code from free dashboard html template on the internet and try to apply it to my project

If you look at your base template it already has the head and body tag, etc. and the body tag has a content block which your dashboardowner/index.html template tries to fill with yet another head and body tag. Simply put you're producing some pretty weird (and invalid) HTML and the browser is trying to do its best with it.
